# Issue involving arbitrage conditions

Tags: arbitrage

In my book it's written that if one of these two conditions is verified then you can make an arbitrage. The two conditions are:
$$1)
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
 \mathbf{q} \bullet\mathbf{n} \le0 \\ 
\mathbf{Y}=D\mathbf{n} \ \ has \ at \ least \ one  \ component >0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
$$2)
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
 \mathbf{q} \bullet\mathbf{n} <0 \\ 
\mathbf{Y}=D\mathbf{n} \ \ has \ at \ least \ one  \ component \ge 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
Where: 
$\mathbf{n}$ is the fraction of each title one has bought at t=0;
$\mathbf{Y}$ is the portfolio payoff in each of the 'S' possible states of the world at t=1;
$D$ is the matrix of the dividends of the N titles in the 'S' states;
$\mathbf{q}$ is the price of each titles;
Further in the book there is also written that an arbitrage occurs when: $$3) \mathbf{Y}>\mathbf{q} \bullet\mathbf{n}$$ where it stays for each component of the vector $\mathbf{Y}$.
 So I'm a bit confused since for example if I have:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
 \mathbf{q} \bullet\mathbf{n} =-5$ \\ 
\mathbf{Y}=[+10$ ;-7$ ;-7$] \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
then $1)$ is verified but not $3)$.
While if $3)$ is verified for example:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
 \mathbf{q} \bullet\mathbf{n} =5$ \\ 
\mathbf{Y}=[+10$ ;7$ ;7$] \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
then $1)$ is not true in general. So I don't understand exactly when you have arbitrage. Is the book wrong?
Thanks

Comment: I am looking at (1) and (2) only. I think the correct statement of (1) is that "all components $\ge 0$ *with at least one component* $>0$". Check your book. In your example you have two -7 components which are negative, so in my opinion (1) is not verified.

Comment: Also in (2) I thiink it should be "every component $\ge 0$".

Comment: It says 'a positive amount of money in at least one of the S states' @AlexC

Comment: That is an incomplete statement. Check for example here http://people.dm.unipi.it/trevisan/didattica/2015-2016/sanminiato/seminar2.pdf on Page 13 or in another trusted reference. One or more states have to be strictly positive **and the other states have to be zero**. If you can lose money in one or more states it is not a  riskless arbitrage.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the book is not clear in that explanation, thanks. @Alex C